# Self XSS vs Reflected XSS

Tags: javascript, security, xss, owasp, web-application-security

What is the difference between self XSS and reflected XSS?
If I find a XSS vulnerability, how do I know whether it is self XSS or reflected XSS ?
I have tried reading a lot of articles on Google but am still confused.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/65142/what-is-reflected-xss#65242

Comment: @Taplar Thanks for the reference. I had refered to this link before too. It mainly talks about Reflected XSS and Stored XSS. I am looking for Reflected XSS vs Self XSS. :)

Comment: What are you calling "Self XSS"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reflected XSS occurs when user input included in the url address is reflected in the page source un-unescape .
Now, a lot of things can be user input such as your input in search form , the url adress itself . an example is

`https://vulnerable.com/<script>alert(1)</script>`
lets say after visiting the url and you check the page source in your browser and you see `<script>alert(1)</script>` somewhere in the page source . This is a reflected xss and can be used to exploit other users since anyone who visited that link will have the xss fired and their cookies stolen if lacking the httponly flag

**Self XSS**
self Xss is an xss that executes in the context of the user who submits the payload . Say web app has profile function and in the profile function you have an option to specify a nickname . now in this web app you cant view other user profiles , meaning thier is no way to make another user view your profile . Most bank apps are like this. Now, if the nick name parameter is vulnerable to xss , The xss here would be self xss because only you can view your user profile and the xss will only execute in your own context . You can agree that stealing your own cookies isnt of any impact

Comment: Okay, so technically if my XSS input is being reflected in the URL then I can call it as a reflected XSS. In all other cases it is a self XSS. Is it correct ?

Comment: you  are partly correct, if its reflected in url it is reflected xss but that doesnt mean other cases are self . self means you can not use it to exploit another user execept your self . read my answer again carefully . self xss can occur as stored xss or Dom xss . what makes it self is who is being exploited here. TLDR: the xss only fires in the browser of the one who put the xss payload . their is no way to make it fire in someone elses browser

Answer (score 2):

Reflected XSS vulnerabilities typically refer to links that you can trick people into clicking - if the user follows them then the javascript is executed, eg `https://www.example.com/example?search=<script>alert(1);</script>`

Self XSS vulnerabilities typically require the user to type something in, such as putting `<script>alert(1);</script>` in a form field where the value is not populated from a URL or form parameter. So you can only impact yourself with self XSS vulnerabilities unless you have a really gullible user :)

Comment: Okay, so technically if my XSS input is being reflected in the URL then I can call it as a reflected XSS. In all other cases it is a self XSS. Is it correct ?

Comment: Its not just the URL, reflected XSSs can be demonstrated by POST requests. Self XSS implies the user has to do something other than just click on a link.